# adding new element to const array in C

Tags: c, arrays, eclipse, parent-child, strcat

I have 2 programs which are main and child. Main calls child. I created a key like below in the main process

```
static const unsigned char key[] = {4,1,8,9,1,61,64,220};
```

and i am displaying it with

```
printf("\nkey:\t %X\n", key);
```

The Result is : 4018EF

the child process

```
static const unsigned char key[] = {4,1,8,9,1,61,64,220};
```

and i am displaying it with

```
printf("\nkey:\t %X\n", key);
```

The Result is: 401061

why are the results different?

Actually I am going to try to add last element, for instance 220, from child and compare two keys. I mean main will be {4,1,8,9,1,61,64,220} and child will be {4,1,8,9,1,61,64}. in a for-loop i will try to add last part. if it hits, then it will say "OK Equals". (i tried to do but failed) Now i am confused because results are different. please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different because they are `static`, so each C file gets its own distinct array.

You are (invalidly) printing the address as an unsigned number (the proper way to print an address is using `%p` and a cast to `void *`), so you get to see that the two arrays reside in different locations.

You cannot "add" to constant array. You can reserve space for one more element and set it to some "not used" value which you later replace, but of course you cannot do that and keep it `const` since you're going to have to write to the array in order to do so.

Comment: thanks..i change the way i am looking to it. Now i have 2 same key on both main and child..